# Java prepared statement does not allow large strings in the where clause of the query

Tags: java, prepared-statement, resultset

I am trying to retrieve data from DB2 using Java prepared statement

```
String select_statement = "SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name where NME='xxx002' and LINE =7200 and FILE_NME='720001042021XYZ002' with ur";

try (Connection connection = DataBaseConnection.getGeoCarDBConnection_TESTDATA(); 
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(select_statement);)  {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
}
```

The problem I am facing is that I include the `FILE_NME` in the where clause of the query, as shown above, 0 rows are returned. But any other string fields can be passed and I get the desired number of rows.

Any `integer` fields in the where clause works too.
But only the `string` fields that are large(In this case, `FILE_NME` field) are not working. In the DB2 table, where I am pulling the data from, the `FILE_NME` field is of `varchar(30)`.

Things that did not work for me was

```
String select_statement = "SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name where NME='xxx002' and LINE =7200 and FILE_NME = ? with ur";
```

then I set the String value using,

```
ps.setString(1, "'720001042021XYZ002'")

ps.setString(1, "720001042021XYZ002")
```

Both did not work.

None of the google links were helpful. Have spent more than a day on it.

This code used to work flawlessly before, Even the java version hasn't changed(as per my knowledge)

> I am running it in windows 10.
>
> Java version : 1.8 ((build 1.8.0_221-b11))

I run the same query in the database client and it works.

Someone please help me or point me in the right direction. I don't know what I am missing

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was indeed no data, I was checking the same query in the database client in a different environment. I am closing this.